# New to Ant, ClassNotFoundException with JUnit

Tags: java, ant, junit

I've been scratching my head over this for a while now (Googled a bunch, looked through other related SO posts to no avail). I have a Java program comprised of two files, `Logic` and `Tests`. `Tests` contains about a hundred JUnit tests, and I've gotten 100% success rate with said tests by calling `javac *.java` followed by `java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Tests`. However when I run my `build.xml` with a simple `ant -verbose test` (in order to follow the output since I'm new to all this), I get the following output:

```
[junit] Testsuite: Tests
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
[junit] 
[junit] Null Test:  Caused an ERROR
[junit] Tests
[junit] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Tests
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
[junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
[junit] 
[junit] 
[junit] Test Tests FAILED

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

My `build.xml` is as follows:

```
<project name="ETL_Automation" default="test" basedir=".">

<path id="classpath.base">
</path>

<path id="classpath.test">
  <pathelement location="${basedir}/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar" />
  <pathelement location="${basedir}/junit-4.10.jar"/>
  <path refid="classpath.base" />
</path>

<target name="compile">
  <javac srcdir="${basedir}">
    <classpath refid="classpath.test"/>
  </javac>
</target>

<target name="test" depends="compile">
  <junit fork="no">
    <classpath refid="classpath.test" />
    <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
    <batchtest>
      <fileset dir="${basedir}/" includes="Tests.class" />
    </batchtest>
  </junit>
</target>

<target name="clean" depends="test">
  <delete>
    <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="*.class"/>
  </delete>
</target>
```

The directory structure is pretty straightforward. `Tests.java`, `Logic.java`, `junit-4.10.jar`, `mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar`, `build.xml`, and a referenced `.properties` file are all in  the same folder. The java code references external files but those are unrelated to this particular issue. I don't know if the classpath could be the cause of this issue (as I'm pretty convinced what I currently have doesn't work).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to add the directory with the `Tests.class` to the `classpath.tests` classpath (which is `${basedir}` in your setup)

Try:

```
<path id="classpath.test"> 
  <pathelement location="${basedir}/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar" /> 
  <pathelement location="${basedir}/junit-4.10.jar"/> 
  <pathelement location="${basedir}" /> 
  <path refid="classpath.base" /> 
</path>
```