# JUnit Ant ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, ant, junit, classpath, build.xml

I am getting a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` when I run my target `TranslatorWorkflow` that is supposed to execute a JUnit test. I am running a `build.xml` file with the targets: `build TranslatorWorkflow`. It compiles but fails on the JUnit test immediately. 
My `TranslatorWorkflow.class` file is in `{basedir}/bin/testScripts/`. My classpath and target are:

**classpath:**

```
<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib/binaries" includes="*.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${basedir}/bin/testScripts/" />
</path>
```

**TranslatorWorkflow target in my build.xml file:**

```
<target name="TranslatorWorkflow">
    <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}" />
    <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
        <formatter type="xml" />
        <test name="testScripts.TranslatorWorkflow" todir="${junit.output.dir}" />
        <classpath refid="classpath" />
    </junit>
</target>
```

I attempted to emulate [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10658714/2877415) by adding the pathelement line shown in my classpath section above, but received the same exception. I've looked at [this question as well as it seems like the same deal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12745714/2877415). I'd imagine there is something super obvious that I'm missing but alas I don't seem to be getting it.

Comment: Are the Junit libs on your classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classpath should reference `${basedir}/bin` not `${basedir}/bin/testScripts` (i.e. it should reference the root of classes directory, not the package in which the class exists):

```
<path id="classpath">
   <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib/binaries" includes="*.jar" />
   <pathelement location="${basedir}/bin/" />
</path>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dumpcats, try this...

```
  <path id="base.path">
    <pathelement path="${sun.boot.class.path}"/>
    <pathelement path="${sun.boot.library.path}"/>
    <fileset dir="${basedir}"> 
       <include name="**.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </path>
```

And then in the target element ...

```
<target name="runTest">
  <mkdir dir="test_reports"/>

  <junit
      fork="true"
      forkmode="once"
      maxmemory="256m">

    <formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>
    <formatter type="xml"/>

    <classpath refid="base.path"/>

    <batchtest
        haltonerror="true" haltonfailure="true"
        todir="test_reports">

      <fileset dir="${test.build}">
        <include name="**/*Test*.class"/>
        <include name="**/Test*.class"/>
        <include name="**/*Test.classp"/>
        <!-- Exclusions -->
        <exclude name="**/util/*.class"/> 
      </fileset>
    </batchtest>
  </junit>
</target>
```

At least is that is how i manage classpath reference and everything works like a charm.

Comment: I'll try this in a bit to make sure it works as well. It appears as though I was referencing a sub-directory when I should have been referencing the root of my classes directory.

Comment: That was exactly i was implicit suggesting to you by...  <fileset dir="${basedir}"> 
       <include name="**.jar"/>
    </fileset>

Comment: @Dumpcats Please Test my answer and comment if it works or not. Now i have the doubt :D

Comment: It may have something to do with how my build.xml file is specifically set up. I took off the /lib/binaries to my fileset dir and it threw back that I needed to include junit.jar if it's not in Ant's own classpath

Comment: Not for me, no ): It could be how my ant build is constructed, though

Comment: I believe that `<fileset dir="${basedir}/lib/binaries" includes="*.jar" />` is including a subset of what is including `<fileset dir="${basedir}"> 
       <include name="**.jar"/>
    </fileset>`.... there must be something strange there.... The `**` includes all the childs.